# Changing taiga-back default port (8000)

Tags: python, api

I want to change the default port of taiga-back api which is 8000. I have another daemon listening to that port that is already in production and I can't change its port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It is done by specifying the port when when executing runserver

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```